# Trouble with log question

Tags: logarithms

I'm doing this question from a past papers and I came across this log question. The question says **write the following logarithmic expression as a single logarithm to base 10** and I have made numberous attempts trying to solve this equation. The question is shown below.

[The second part bit (underneath) is the solution but i dont know how they got from the question to the (9+2/3) part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZzF8.png)

Thanks, 
Neamus

Comment: That step should be $\left(9+\frac{2}{3}\right)\frac{\log(x)}{\log(2)}$ or $\left(9+\frac{2}{3}\right)\log_2(x)$. The $3$ in the denominator comes from $\log(8)=\log(2^3)=3\log(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in there.

$9\log_2 x + 2\log_8 x = 9\frac {\log x}{\log 2} + 2\frac {\log x}{\log 8}\\
\log 8 = \log 2^3 = 3\log 2\\
9\frac {\log x}{\log 2} + 2\frac {\log x}{3\log 2}\\
(9+ \frac 23)\frac {\log x}{\log 2}\\
$

Your worksheet is missing the $\log 2$ in the denominator.

And I hope that this sufficiently covers the missing step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write the following.
$$\frac{29\log{x}}{3\log2}$$
It's all.